# Implementing ancestry on a nested resource throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I am implementing ancestry on a nested resource.

```
resources :loads do
  resources :messages
end
```

Here is my index action

```
def index
  load = Load.find(params[:load_id])
  @messages = load.messages.scoped
  @message = load.messages.new
end
```

My index.html.erb is throwing the following error.

> Missing partial messages/message with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
>   * "C:/Sites/final/cloud/app/views"

My index.html.erb is as follow

```
<% title "Messages" %>

<%= nested_messages @messages.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>

<%= render "form" %>
```

Here is my nested_message definition

```
module MessagesHelper
  def nested_messages(messages)
  messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
  render(message) + content_tag(:div, nested_messages(sub_messages), :class => "nested_messages")
   end.join.html_safe
  end
end
```

Here is my _message.html.erb

```
<div class="message">
<div class="created_at"><%= message.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></div>
<div class="content">
 <%= link_to message.content, message %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= link_to "Reply", new_load_message_url(:parent_id => message) %> |
<%= link_to "Destroy", [message.load, message], :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error states that your application has tried to search for a partial _messages.html.erb, as a result of this the partial must not be in your `/app/views/messages` which results in the message you are being shown. Check your `messages` directory and check if you have this partial. Going by your nested resources I am guessing your association between `Load` and `Message` is:

```
class Load < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :load
end
```

Further more I noticed that you have the following line in your `index` action: `@message = load.messages.new` surely this does not seem right. Because what your telling your application to do is when the controller recieves a response to render the `index` action it should also create message by doing `@message = load.messages.new` which is why it is trying to render the partial.

To clarify things a bit more for you. If in your application you had a `link_to` to create a new user. Upon clicking the new user it will do something like:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

And will render `app/views/users/new.html.erb which inside this will most probably have a

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :f => f } %>
<% end %>
```

This will call your partial which in normal cases would be `_form.html.erb`. The create action of a particular controller will come into play when you attempt to save the partial. Usually a `create` block for a controller will look like this:

```
 def create
    @title = "Create a user"
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      redirect_to usermanagement_path
      flash[:success] = "Created successfully."
    else
      @title = "Create a user"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here inside the `create` action when your `_form.html.erb` or `_message.html.erb` is submitted it will try to create a new user by passing in the user through the `params`. I do thoroughly believe that your issue may potentially well be:

1) Your missing your _message.html.erb

2) Also you are calling a `.new` inside your `index` action.

Hope this clears this up for you.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the detailed response. I do have a _message.html.erb in my model. I am editing my post to include this. I also tried commenting out the .new inside index action, but I am getting the same error

Comment: @user2297820 another thing I just noticed in the code snippets you provided I don't see where you are calling `<%= render "message" %>` also you could alternaitvely try adding the extension explicitly to `<%= render :partial => "messages/_message.html.erb"`. You will notice inside your `index.html.erb` you are calling `<%= render "form" %>` I believe you want `<%= render "message" %>` if I stand correct

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback guys. Really appreciate it. It is working now. I had my partial names as _messages.html.erb instead of _message.html.erb. Once again really appreciate your help.